# grepl function in R

Tags: r

I have a data set and I want to find the rows which include a specific word "result". I used the following function but it seems it doesn't work correctly. Any suggestion?

```
data$new<-data.frame(grepl("result",col1)) 


data:
col1                            col2
ABC result VDCbvdc home          22
fgc school                       34
university result home exam      45
exam math stat                   65
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do, and how does that differ from what happens?

Answer (score 1):

try `data$new <- grepl("result",data$col1)`

`data$new` should be assigned to a vector, but you're trying to feed it a data frame. also, `col1` only exists inside `data`, so you'll need `data$col1`.